# prevent click event in webview in tabs when scrolling

Tags: android, webview, gesturedetector

I am using [ViewPager Extension](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) to make my app have tab functionality. There are two tabs in my app we named tabA and tabB here. tabA includes a webview component and tabB includes a listview.

Now, I am encountering an issue:
once I try to scroll from tabA to tabB, the page in the tabA is changed when(or before) the changed to tabB. In other word, my requirement is donot trigger the click event in tabA when I try to scroll from tabA to tabB.

Does anyone any ideas or experience about the issue, many thanks!

I have tried to use GestureDetector to detect the gesture as folloing, but it does not work for me.

```
final GestureDetector dector = new GestureDetector(new OnGestureListener(){...}
webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        return dector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is that

1. detect the swipe and set a flag then

   ```
   public interface TouchDelegate {
      public void gestureHandler(String msg, float downX, float downY);

      public boolean notASwipe(View v, MotionEvent event);
   }

   public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

      private TouchDelegate mView;
      static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
      private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
      public SwipeDetector(TouchDelegate view) {
         this.mView = view;
      }

      public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
         mView.gestureHandler("R2L", downX, downY);
      }

      public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
         mView.gestureHandler("L2R", downX, downY);
      }

      public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
         mView.gestureHandler("T2B", downX, downY);
      }

      public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
         mView.gestureHandler("B2T", downX, downY);
      }

      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
          downX = event.getX();
          downY = event.getY();
          return true;
      }
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
          upX = event.getX();
          upY = event.getY();

          float deltaX = downX - upX;
          float deltaY = downY - upY;

          // swipe horizontal?
          if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
              // left or right
              if (deltaX < 0) {
                  this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                  return true;
              }
              if (deltaX > 0) {
                  this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                  return true;
              }
          } else {
              // swipe vertical?
              if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                  // top or down
                  if (deltaY < 0) {
                      this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                      return true;
                  }
                  if (deltaY > 0) {
                      this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                      return true;
                  }
              } else {
                  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                          "SwipeDetector: onTouch: Swipe was only x: " + Math.abs(deltaX)
                               + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
               Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                       "SwipeDetector: onTouch: Swipe was only y: "
                               + Math.abs(deltaY)
                               + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
               return mView.notASwipe(v, event); // We don't consume the
                                                   // event
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
   }
   return false;
   }
   }
   ```
2. override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading to disable all the links on the webview. Here is the code to disable all the links on the webview:

   ```
   public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shuldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
       if(swipe)              
          return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
      if (!swipe) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
      }
      return true;
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for you answer. but i still not clear where should I set swip value. and also, I just want to disable during scrolling rather than disable all the links on the webview.

Comment: I added the code you need to detect the swipe, basically your view should implement the TouchDelegate and then set the onTouchListener of your view to be one instance of the swipedetector class!

Comment: I tried this just now but unlucky. I tried as following in : `webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { swipe = dector.onTouch(v, event); return swipe; } }); ` On the other hand, Looks webview will not trigger the click event when scroll up/down. Do you know how does the webview control this?

Comment: the code format looks really sucks in the comments, please just copy the code to your editor to make it more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `WebView`, then override the `onTouchEvent` method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // If this web view gets sent a 'CANCEL' event, it means the 
    // parent view has intercepted the event (for scrolling / swiping),
    // so we want to catch it, otherwise it propagates into the HTML 
    // and triggers the click
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

What should happen is that the enclosing ViewPager is already intercepting the touch events when there's a proper swipe, which sends the `ACTION_CANCEL` event to the WebView. By catching that `ACTION_CANCEL` event in the `onTouchEvent` method, it prevents the event from going down into the HTML in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I have searched several ideas that required coding in java but I thought this is not good, easy, clean way. Then I found a solution that is very easy and clean. You just need to use this line `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` Use this line of code in webView's parent in XML. Thats it